# How to initialize a \x23 value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to save a hex value like 0x23 as string:

```
var x = "\x23";
```

This causes:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I tried to escape it:

```
var x = "\\x23";
```

But this cannot be right because the value of the variable will be

```
\\x23
```

Am I missing something? How can I stringify a hex value and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/FA9Gn/

Comment: @adeneo but it does not work for me !

Comment: @AliRashidi - Then you're probably using the wrong browser, works just fine for me in Chrome!

Comment: @adeneo it doesn't make sense. :-s

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is for nodejs

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve (or the exact problem), but maybe `String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x23'))` in fact you don't need the `parseInt` and so `String.fromCharCode('0x23')`: `0x23` is a string, converts to a number with `parseInt` which is `35`, char `35` is `#`. Or please explain the problem in greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "\x23" is perfectly legit and my Node.js doesn't complain about it.

I suspect that **you have an invisible character** somewhere in your JavaScript source.  Possibly a non-breaking whitespace, esp. if you copied your JavaScript from some web page.

See if your text editor has the option to show invisibles.